# Ошибка в поиске mySQL

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

```
$number = $_GET['number'];
$number = str_replace('%20',' ',$number);
$query = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE auto_numbers='$number'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
print_r($result);
```

Выводит Resource id #6, хотя к базе подключен и вроде все хорошо. Напрямую через phpmyadmin запрос работает.

***Добавленно:***

Меня настолько заела это проблема, что готов раскрыть пасы.

Покажите, как правильно выбрать "SELECT * FROM company WHERE auto_numbers='$number'"; где $number = "В132СВ47";

Comment: Ошибки нету, просто вы не ту переменную выводите.

Comment: Извините, я уже не помню `php_mysql`, но посмотрите ж таки мануалы. Если не ошибаюсь, то там надо же ещё какой-нибудь fetch сделать, а не только выполнить `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$number = str_replace('%20', ' ', mysql_escape_string($_GET['number']));
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE `auto_numbers` = '$number'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Ваш вариант оказался самым правильным.

Comment: @ModaL, глаза режет

>> = '$number'"

Правильно будет 

>> = '". mysql_real_escape_string($number) ."'" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Может вам нужно выводить не **print_r($query)**, а **print_r($result)**?

Также на всякий случай обратите внимание на *auto_nubers*, у вас там буква **m** пропущена.

Comment: Эти ошибки были когда я задал вопрос, я их исправил уже давно но проблема есть и сейчас.

Вот непосредственный запрос к бд http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i3/51ec171b1d33c8-36507972

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно в чем проблема. B132CB47 этого номера просто нет в auto_numbers. 
Запросы полей заключай еще вот так:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE `auto_numbers`='$number'";
```

Comment: http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i3/51ec171b1d33c8-36507972 она существует

Comment: $result будет ассоциативным массивом если применить
    mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 

тогда

    echo $result['name_column'];
    //или
    echo $result['auto_company'];

выведет нужный результат

если
    mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $result[1];

порядковый номер столбца

Comment: ошибки все идут, попробуй сам сделать доступ я дал в верхнем посте

Comment: какие ошибки идут? я сейчас не могу подключиться.

Comment: кто-то очень злой дропнул таблицу :D